# React onSubmit handler on a form won't be called if I have a onBlur handler on an input? (Only happens when using Webstorm js debugger)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webstorm

A simplified version of my code. If I click the submit button by itself, the onSubmit handler is called. 
If I click submit right after editing the input box, the onSubmit handler won't be called. Is this how React is designed? How to call onSubmit in this case.

```
const EmailInput = React.createClass({
    handleOnBlur(event){
        console.log('onBlur')
    },
    render(){
        return <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor={this.props.name}>Email</label>
            <input className="form-control"
                type='text'
                name={this.props.name}
                onBlur={this.handleOnBlur}
                value={this.state.val}
            />
        </div>
    }
})

const Form = React.createClass({
    onSubmit(e){
         console.log('onSubmit')
    },
    render(){
        return <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>{this.props.children}</form>
    }
})

ReactDOM.render(<Form>
         <EmailInput />   
         <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" >Share</button>
        </Form>, mountNode)
```

Based on Dhaval's answer, I found the reason of this.

When I use Webstorm js debugger, the submit event won't fire. When I just use the browser by itself. It works out fine.

This is so weird that I doubt I'm doing something wrong. Can someone try it on the Webstorm.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the below mentioned Plunkar when I click on Share button it will called onSubmit

```
    // Code goes here
var EmailInput = React.createClass({
    handleOnBlur(event){
        console.log('onBlur')
    },
    getInitialState:function()
    {
      return{
        val:''
      }
    },
    render(){
        return <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor={this.props.name}>Email</label>
            <input className="form-control"
                type='text'
                name={this.props.name}
                onBlur={this.handleOnBlur}
                value={this.state.val}
            />
        </div>
    }
});
var Form = React.createClass({
    onSubmit(e){
         console.log('onSubmit')
    },
    render(){
        return <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>{this.props.children}</form>
    }
});
React.render(<Form><EmailInput /><button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" >Share</button></Form>,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/a9AJthqcLF8RgI2WUlvH)

Comment: @jackyzhai: I don't have WS :(